# Invalid android_key parameter while using facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting below error when i try running my app on S3

```
    Invalid android_key parameter. The key VgmNos1v_wYCwwxenlSneyDLza8 
does not match any allowed key. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/299************
```

I generated a key hash on my 1st laptop and added that on facebook developer site.. All went fine and when i ran, it asked for SSO on emulator and hence forth i was able to post.

After few days i started working on different laptop, and ran on S3 and got this error. After googling i found that we need to add this as key hash. I added key VgmNos1v_wYCwwxenlSneyDLza8 which was in the error and tried but dint work. So i generated a key hash on the 2nd laptop and received a key hash vyCoFm3xLkoFa8lp7l+LIAGhIe4= which was different from the one in the error. So i added both but still the error persist.

Please help me out as i stuck at this point very badly :(

Please Notes: I am still in debug mode.

I want to know is key hash related to machines? each machine has unique key hash?
I used below command to generate a key hash on 2nd laptop

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\605577709\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes keyhash depends on `androiddebugkey` & it varies according to device.So you can do either -

1. Copy `debug.keystore` file from user's directory->.android from old m/c to new m/c.
2. Use this code to get new key hash -

   ```
   try{ logger.debug("Checking signs");
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
       for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           logger.debug(Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
       }
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       logger.debug(e.getMessage());
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       logger.debug(e.getMessage());
   }`
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot lot lot :) I used the above code snippet to generate the key hash and it was same as in error except = at the last :) i added the generated key hash in facebook developer and it worked :)